# Does "reset this pc" work on a Bootcamp Windows 10?

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, windows, startup

I want to Reset my Windows 10 back to its factory state. I installed Windows 10 thru bootcamp partition. Does the "Reset this PC" option work on it? If not how should I reset my windows partition?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Reset this PC option and if it doesn't work, simply copy and files to iCloud, OneDrive, etc or a hard drive and then remove the Bootcamp partition from macOS and reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: What will happen to the bootcamp drivers?

Comment: Drivers should remain but just in case back up your files and be prepared to redo Bootcamp if it doesn't work.

Comment: I will try it and let you know :)

Comment: Great! Also, you can reinstall Windows Support Software from Bootcamp if drivers do get corrupted or deleted.

Comment: My drivers died where should I install it?

Comment: Boot Camp Assistant > Action > Download Windows Support Software. Then, you will need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, and things got weird.  It reset to like an old version of Windows Home, something I didn't have on any ISO when I made the partition in bootcamp.  It was super laggy, looked like garbage, so I ended up just erasing the whole partition and starting over from zero.